# How to remove all response headers in restful (jersey - Spring)

Tags: java, spring, http-headers, jersey-2.0

For my restful webservices, I would like to remove all response headers.
I have tried using `ContainerResponseFilter` to remove headers.

I found only `Content-Type` there and able to remove it.

Following headers are still there inside response.

```
1. Date
2. Content-Length
3. #status#
4. Server
5 .X-Powered-By
```

I am using

```
 1. spring-jersey 
 2. Glassfish 4.1
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want that? Content-Type, Length and data are generally required by the client, removing them can break clients using your service. The others (Server, X-Powered-By) can generally be removed by configuring your server correctly those aren't application related.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum, I can remove X-Powered-By and Server headers at glassfish console now.